# Docker command that purges everything

Tags: docker

Is there a single docker command that can be used to purge everything? Stop all containers if running, delete all images, delete all volumes... ect.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is a single command to do that. You first need to stop all containers using

```sh
$ docker stop `docker ps -qa` > /dev/null 2>&1; ## Stop all running containers
$ docker system prune --volumes --all; ## Remove all unused docker components
```

Usage on prune can be found in [docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#examples).

You can still run the above 2 commands in a single line.

```sh
$ docker stop `docker ps -qa` > /dev/null 2>&1; docker system prune --volumes --all;
```

Or an alias should help

```sh
alias dockerRemoveAll="docker stop `docker ps -qa` > /dev/null 2>&1; docker system prune --volumes --all;"
```

Edit-1:
Based on [@Zeitounator's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator) comment, I've added `> /dev/null 2>&1` to redirect whatever the output is to null and stderr. This still continues to remove all the docker contents even when the exit code is 1 for the stop command when there are no containers.

Also [@Zeitounator's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator) [wipedocker function](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/85e237b30e2230adabb1b581adc4f0e4) is even more elegant.

Comment: True, this would be the best option.

Comment: By passing `-a` to `docker ps` your are trying to stop already stopped containers. Also the command will fail if there are no (running) containers. Although it probably goes far beyond what is asked here, here is a [`wipedocker` function](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/85e237b30e2230adabb1b581adc4f0e4) I load in my environment which does the job and is a single command in the end. This can easily be turned into an executable script rather than a function.

Comment: AFAIK, the more modern `$(...)` is preferred over the older backtick syntax, i.e. `docker stop $(docker ps -qa)`